# Best approach for entityframework core multi tenancy

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

We develop a bigger SaaS application based on ASP.NET Core and EFCore. We separate tenants by database, means that we have one database for each tenant.

The database is migrated on any incoming request by a client by a custom middleware. This required, because the application should be immediately available after a tenant signed up on our SSO-Server.

So the pipeline looks like this:

1. Authentication Middleware (ASP.NET Core Standard)
2. UserResolverMiddleware (extracts TenantID from the JWT token and adds it to HttpContext.Items)
3. TenantDatabaseInitializerMiddleware (constructs a TenantDbContext object by passing the tenantid in the ConnectionString and starts migration)

Unfortunately this has some downsides, as I recognized later:

1. The TenantDatabaseInitializer sometimes uses an TenantDbContext of a different tenant. Therefore no database is migrated and the whole request fails.
2. If there are a lot of incoming requests for the same tenant, the migrations often overlap and fail. (The Middleware is catching the InvalidOperationExceptions that are thrown, but this does not seem as good solution).
3. It creates a lot of databases.
4. The requests take potentially long to complete (check for migration).

Long introduction, short question: Can anyone judge whether this migration workflow is a good practise? If not: Do you have a better idea how I can achieve multi tenancy?

I read about Global Query Filters in EFCore 2.0, but I'm not sure how safe this approach is regarding data isolation.

Thanks!

Comment: What database server are you using?

Comment: PostgreSQL running on Amazon RDS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think creating a database per each tenant is not practical. If you have 2000 tenants, then you have to maintain 2000 database instances!

I recommend using 1 database for all the application and tenants. And add a `TenantId` to most of tables so you can find out which tenant this specific records belong to.

Comment: Thanks, that's also my impression now. I always wanted to avoid this because I was afraid of the hassle of adding a TenantId check to each IQueryable, but I think this can be accomplished pretty easily by use of the available Global Query Filters. :)

Comment: Yes, global query filters can help a lot. It also is helpful in soft delete. http://gunnarpeipman.com/2017/08/ef-core-global-query-filters/

Comment: @asfhar, tenant can be switched by user or if the user, trying to login the app, may not have a tenant id. if application services apis need to have tenant, the global filter cant be ok because tenant usually changes per request, so it makes sense to apply that filter within a request-scoped context. generic extension is good to use in such cases

Comment: @tiakham can you please provide a link or an example for that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @curiousBoy i dont have any link but my solution is like kind of a bit different way. i coded an ef extension method,  name is FilterByTenant as follow, to filter context data for tenantid after i get the tenantid of the usercontext per the request where needed tenantid, like that                             
 **var customer = await context.Customers.FilterByTenant(userAccessor.GetTenantId())**                  
 this makes code short instead of using more 2-3 extra line code. this is a practical way for me for now but if i can find any other solution more generic, i am gonna pick that up.